# Gatling Java Performance Testing With Token Renewal Every 10 Minutes

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, performance-testing, gatling

I am utilizing Gatling in Java to measure the API's performance. The objective is to measure the performance of the user API, which requires a token. This token expires every 10 minutes. Is it feasible to obtain the token only once every 10 minutes and reset ? Below scenario executes both the API together but I want to execute /token only once every 10 minutes and update access token.

```
public class GetTokenAndUserSimulation extends Simulation {

    HttpProtocolBuilder httpProtocol = http.baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
            .check(status().is(200));

    ScenarioBuilder scn = scenario("OAuth Token and User Request")
        .exec(http("OAuth Token Request")
            .post("/token")
            .header("Authorization", "Basic "+TOKEN)
            .check(status().is(200))
            .check(jsonPath("$.access_token").saveAs("accessToken")))
        .exec(http("User Request")
            .get("/user")
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer ${accessToken}")
            .check(status().is(200)));

    {
        setUp(scn.injectOpen(constantUsersPerSec(REQUEST_PER_SECOND).during(Duration.ofMinutes(DURATION_MIN))))
                .protocols(httpProtocol)
                .assertions(global().responseTime().percentile3().lt(P95_RESPONSE_TIME_MS),
                        global().successfulRequests().percent().gt(95.0));
    }
}
```

Comment: This question has already been answered multiple times on the official Gatling community forum, eg https://community.gatling.io/t/able-to-refresh-token-but-running-refresh-token-scenario-in-sequential-scenarios-is-not-working/7998/3